# popover hover on table header Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, bootstrap-4, hover, popover

I have the following html

```html
<th  scope="col" class="table-success titlerow featurecol"
     id='headerPop'>
    Some Text Header
    <sup>
        <a href='' class="fas fa-info"></a>
    </sup>
</th>
```

and the Meteor javascript file

```js
Template.nameTemplate.events({ 
'mouseenter #headerPop':async function (event,instance){

      instance.$(event.currentTarget).popover({
        html:true,
        title:'The title',
        content:'Some text here'

      })
}
})
```

It seems though that the popover never appears, what is wrong here?
I need the popover message to appear every time the user hovers on the header column of the table

Answer (score 0):

> I need the popover message to appear every time the user hovers on the header column of the table

This indicates, that [you need an event](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-events) to trigger the popover, rather than the `onRendered` callback (Which is [not intended to control event flow](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-onRendered)).

The "hover" functionality can be realized using [`mouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event) or [`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event) (you need to find out which suits your needs, but `mouseenter` seems to be a good candiate):

```js
Template.nameTemplate.events({
  'mouseenter th' (event, templateInstance) {
    const title = templateInstance.title.get()
    templateInstance.$(event.currentTarget).popover({ title })
  }
})
```

You may play with the selector here, which is in the example `th` but you may specify a more narrow scope using class selectors.

Comment: Hi @Jankapunkt i used your suggester code above with event on id instead of th to eliminate the event effect.I can see from the logs that it is triggered but the popover content, title does not appear.(I deleted the on rendered function). Should I return the title /content with a helper or sth similar?

Comment: I updated my answer. If you have a dynamic title then you may use a `ReactiveVar` (alternatively a `ReactiveDict`) and pass the title to the popover function.

Comment: The title and content is static, so rewrote the event handler as above(check my code) but still it does not appear...